# Find ID in Database Table and Select Value from Column

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Okay, so first allow me to outline what I'm trying to do. I want to display a DIV in my view that's only displayed to users of a certain 'subscription' type.

So I'm searching the 'subscriptions' table using the user's session ID to find their subscription on the database (subscriptions are stored with user id as primary). Once their row is found with their subscription, I want to grab the value from the "subscription" column. If the value equals "freebie" I want to echo a statement (I will add a function here once i get it to work obviously).

Here's what I've come up with...what am I doing wrong? Not working and I'm receiving no error.

```
    // show appropiate upgrade message if user has free account

    $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); 

    $this->db->select('subscription');
    $this -> db -> where('id', '$id');
    $query = $this -> db -> get("subscriptions");
    $subscribe = $query -> result();

    if($subscribe == 'freebie')
    {
        echo 'function goes here';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try this     (I am not sure about your column names, this is a example )

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); 

$this->db->select('subscription');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get("subscriptions");
$subscribe = $query->result_array();

if($subscribe[0]['subscription'] == 'freebie')
{
    echo 'function goes here';
}else{
   echo "No Result";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. Error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Column names are: id, email, and subscription

Comment: Saw your edit. Just tried it and the error is gone. But no echo. No error either.

Comment: exactly...I just verified on the table..and the "subscription" column has "freebie" too

Comment: Question - what exactly is this doing: $subscribe[0]['subscription'] ?

Comment: $subscribe is a array of result

Comment: Meaning, in non-computer language, $subscribe[0]['subscription'] doing? What's the [0] for one...

Comment: result_array() we get multidimensional array you can find this using print_r($subscribe)